# Is it possible to restore a SQL Server backup to a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to restore a backup to a different database than the original.

I did backup for `databaseA`, but want to restore to `databaseB`. I want to test first and get the data from the backup, then just take the data I need to update `databaseA`.

How to do this?

Comment: i created databaseB, and went to restore from the backup for databaseA, and got error saying it is not original.

Comment: Show us your effort then....Please post your query so that We can understand the problem in better way....

Comment: i'm not using query... i'm using the GUI sql server.

Comment: I'm **100% sure** you will find the answer in [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) if you just simply search for `RESTORE` .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore to a different database in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267273/how-to-restore-to-a-different-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

In the GUI

- Your source Database is "DatabaseA"
- Your destination database if "DatabaseB"

On the Files tab, you'll need to provide new file names.

[image]

Comment: I found the solution.  it was so easy, its ridiculous!   I just entered a new name for the destination database.  It created a new db for me.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx