# How to add data in database from .bak file by sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have backup files. I want to add that data to the existing database not over write it. 
Scenario: 
The software is installed on different systems. The data is entered from different PC's. but the data is of same type. After taking the backup(.bak)file on run-time. Now i want to combine that all data in a single database not overwrite it. I have tried [How to restore to a different database in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267273/how-to-restore-to-a-different-database-in-sql-server,but) I am out of that option  and after so much googling i cant get answer.Just found to overwrite the database but i dont want to loose any of the data. Thankz

Comment: What about adding the `.bak` to a new database, extracting data as CSV and load that to the target database?

Comment: I am new to this part of database of restoring and backup so can you please elaborate

Comment: What format are the backup files in?

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql server?

Comment: The backup files are in .bak. @Pekka and it is in local server in visual studio.I think it would be Sql Server

Comment: "I am out of that option" – what do you mean? You can't restore a .bak file? If so, you are out of options completely, because there is no other way to use a backup file. Maybe you just need to export your data differently, not through a backup. Only you can tell.

Comment: And  how is that possible