# SQL database backup and restore on user id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I have a database which contains details about user information.The database contains 20 tables with users specific details.Every table contains user foreign key. I want to be able to backup specific user data from the database and restore the backup. Is it possible to restore the backup on a different database that has  same tables. I am working on this but not able to find a documentation or article on this. If you could help me on this if doing this is possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for your query but this thread might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267273/how-to-restore-to-a-different-database-in-sql-server

Comment: First pick a db platform. You have 3 tags above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some SQL to export the data. You can use a number of techniques for example:
Gather data using views, stored procedures or a combination of both.
Export data using linked servers, import export or SSIS.

There is no backup and restore functionality for a subset if data.

(p.s. This is for SQL Server. You have three different database engines in your tags.)