# Restore .bak file in 2 different databases via T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have created a backup of database `A1234` as file `A1234.bak`.

I want to restore this `A1234.bak` in 2 different databases say D1 and D2 in same sql server instance.

I want same data in both the databases.

I've tried

```
RESTORE DATABASE D1 
FROM disk='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\A1234.bak'
```

This works for D1. When I try for D2 It gives error that A1234 is already created and cannot be overwritten.

when I see in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\` location, there is database A1234.mdf and A1234_log.ldf files and no D1. 

while in SSMS it shows D1 and no A1234.
 So I guess the database A1234 is just pointed to D1.

How can I just restore the schema and data in any database I want using .bak file.
I've seen some `WITH MOVE` commands but can't understand it

Edit : Also Tried like this

```
RESTORE DATABASE D1 FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\A1234.bak'
WITH MOVE 'A1234' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\D1.mdf',
MOVE 'A1234_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\D1_log.ldf',
GO
```

Comment: See here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/122/retore-sql-server-database-to-different-file-name-and-location/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore to a different database in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267273/how-to-restore-to-a-different-database-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Matt So I need to do like write its logical name and move its both logical names to my desired name. Okay

Comment: @PeterB got it.

Comment: @Matt Okay I did the restore process but now the new database D1 is not accessible, in SSMS -> Databases section, it shows D1 (Restoring...). Database is not that big. hardly 20 MB. And it restores fast manually from ssms. Seems to be stuck on some process.

Comment: Are you sure `D1` and `D1_log` are your logical names on that database? Try `A1234` and `A1234_log`

Comment: @Matt My mistake writing logical names here. Its A1234 and A1234_log respectively. But why it shows restoring in SSMS. I had given enough time

Comment: @Matt Okay got it. I also have to use `WITH REPLACE,RECOVERY`

Comment: @Matt I Still have a problem shrinking the new D1_log. Do I every time need to mention the logical name of the D1 database (which is A1234) like this `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('A1234_log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)`  ?